# Scope of a 'for' loop

Tags: java, for-loop

From what I know, the scope of a 'for' loop, without a set of parentheses after it, is just one statement. Right?

So how come this code:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        if(x < 2)
            System.out.println("hello");
            System.out.println("world");
```

gives the output:

```
hello
hello
world
```

Is the statement in the `if` is also considered part of the *for* loop? Of course it is, but my question is: Why?

Does what actually is that that the scope is a block right after for statement because the above code when modified like this:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        if(x < 2) {
            System.out.println("hello");
            System.out.println("world");
        }
```

gives the output:

```
hello
world
hello
world
```

Most of the answers are about explaining the flow control in the above code. I already know that. My question was about the rule of the *for* loop scope.

Is the rule actually that: *the scope of an braceless `for` loop is the next block of statements immediately after it?*

Comment: The second `println` is outside of the scope of the `for` and executes after the loop completes.

Comment: see my answer which hopefully addresses what you've asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [Braceless if considered harmful](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/). This post was specifically made because of examples just like this; the confusion that brace-less control flow statements can leave you scratching your head for quite a while, especially with misleading indentation (such as in your example).

The code you pasted is equivalent to the following,

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  if (x < 2) {
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
}
/* outside of the for */
System.out.println("world");
```

As you can see, the loop iterates three times; the first two, it will print `"hello"`. After the loop completes, it will print `"world"`.

---

The reason this works is clear in reading [Chapter 14 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html). In fact, it makes sense to think of *blocks* as statements, as per [§14.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5).

> ```
> for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
>    if (x < 2) 
>       System.out.println("hello");
>       System.out.println("world");
> ```

Looking at the descriptions of [`if` (§14.9)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) and [**basic** `for` (§14.14.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1), we see both merely take a statement; in this case, we can see our `for` statement contains `if` statement, which itself encapsulates your `println("hello")` statement. Following the `for` statement, you then have your `println("world")` statement.

> ```
> for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
>     if (x < 2) { 
>       System.out.println("hello");
>       System.out.println("world");
>     }
> ```

Here, we see the `for` statement body is the `if` statement, which encapsulates a *block* that contains **2** statements, namely both your `println` statements. Note that this is indeed not the same as the former.

Hopefully this clears things up for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
First x=0
 Then if (x < 2) condition satisfies (again no braces, so only one statement executes)
   Prints "hello"
for loop continues
x=1
 Then if (x < 2) condition satisfies (again no braces, so only one statement executes)
   Prints "hello"
  for loop continues
x=2
 Then if (x < 2) condition NOT satisfies, so if statement won' execute, moves to print "world"
   Prints "world"
```

First snippet will be treated like:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        if(x < 2) {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
}
            System.out.println("world");
```

Answer (score 1):

The one line after the loop ,condition is considered in the body of   loop ,condition you did not use the `{}` so the only `if` is consider in the for body

```
   for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        if(x < 2) 
            System.out.println("hello");
            System.out.println("world");
```

gives the output `hello hello world` because

the only 1 line after the if statement is consider in the for loop when the loop end the `world` print

its like

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
      {  if(x < 2) 
            System.out.println("hello");
       }
     System.out.println("world");
```

and in the

```
 for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        if(x < 2) { 
            System.out.println("hello");
            System.out.println("world");
        }
```

the both     `System.out.println("hello");   System.out.println("world");` consider in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

When you don't put `{}` only next line after the loop or conditional statement is considered as a part of its scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing the right thing. It prints "hello" for i = 0 and 1 and then for loop ends and "world" is printed.

I think you are confused by the alignment, following is how the first one should look -

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    if(x < 2) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
System.out.println("world");
```

And the second one -

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    if(x < 2) { 
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println("world");
    }
}
```

More readable and easy to understand the logic.

Answer (score -1):

See it like this...

`for` and `if` have **control over next statement** or **next block enclosed in `{...}`**.

If `{}` are missing only next statement is considered as the body.

In first case, i have corrected indentation so that body part is clearly visible.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)  
    if(x < 2)   
        System.out.println("hello");
System.out.println("world");
```