# Confusing indentation, why and how it can happen

Tags: java, if-statement, warnings, indentation

This is actually not a problem for solving but I felt curious that why the following code would gives the `confusing indentation` warning for possible missing of surrounding block:

```
if(x!=y)
System.out.println("not equal"); 
index++;
```

If I put the `System.out.println("not equal");` inside `{}` the warning would go away but I feel curious in what situation the current looking code would go wrong.

Comment: It is confusing because the `System.out.println` has the same indentation as the `index++` line, but one is part of the `if` statement, and the other is not.

Comment: @But does this have anything with, say, in some cases we get a wrong result? For example, the condition does not satisfies and then the third line does not execute , while it should be?

Comment: The warning is telling you that the code is confusing to read, not that it won't work. It just might not do what a reader would expect, because the indentation is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything within an if statement is generally indented for clarity. For instance:

```
if(foo) {
    if (bar) {
       System.out.println("foo bar");
    }
}
```

As you are writing only a 1 line statement, you don't need the `{}` but indentation is still recommended. Without it, it is not immediately obvious what will and won't get executed.

For instance, if someone reading your code didn't know that only 1 line get's executed in an if statement with no brackets, they might think the `index++;` line will only get called if `(x!=y)`

Also, you are more likely to make mistakes as a developer if you don't use `{}` for all if statements. If you get into the habit of not using them, and you forget to use them for a multi-line if statement, you will get unexpected results. For instance, if you decided to put something after the `System.out.println("not equal");` within the if block, it would be very easy to forget the `{}`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that, when you read this code, you are missing a visual cue that the `System.out.println("not equal");` is only run when the condition `(x!=y)` is true. The error will go away as well when you indent the code:

```java
if (x != y)
   System.out.println("not equal");
```

Some people may still advise against using single-line consequences and encourage you to use blocks anyway. People might be tempted to just add another line of code underneath the `System.out`, thinking that it will also just be executed when `x != y` - without noticing that the braces are missing.

Comment: Good lord, I did not know a simple white space means that much. Is it a warning only for readability of the code or what?

Comment: Yes, and to give you a warning that this code may be prone to problems caused by misreading the code. As I said - if you add another line and fail to notice that the braces are missing, your program will not behave as you expect it to. This has indeed happened to me more often than I dare to admit.

Comment: Both. Readability and bug prevention.

Comment: but how does it make a bug? if the condition does not satisfy then the second line would be executed(which is my intention). in fact, how a white space produces a remedy for a bug?

Comment: Imagine that the line was different and instead of a `System.out` you'd have something else like

`if (x != y)`
`c++;`

You haven't edited your code for half a year when some bug comes up that needs fixing. So you add some log messages to help you. But you're under a lot of stress and you just skimmed over the code, so you end up writing:

`if (x != y)`
`logger.log("Executed if x is not equal y");`
`c++;`

You made a mistake, of course, you just added a bug. But without the visual cue, it was easy to overlook that you needed to add braces for this to work correctly.