# error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’ with fprintf

Tags: c, gcc

I want to print on the screen index of velocity.I am not author of the code.

Code is here http://pastebin.com/47CbB1vb

And get line is also necessary for compilation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*
*   get_line:
*       Reads a line into string, returns length.
*       Kernighan & Ritchie p.69
*
*/
int
get_line(fp, line, lim)
   FILE           *fp;
   char           *line;
   int             lim;
{
   int             c, i;

   i = 0;
   while (--lim > 0 && (c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
      line[i++] = c;
   if (c == '\n')
   {
      line[i++] = c;
   }
   line[i] = '\0';
   if (c == EOF)
      return (-1);
   else
      return (i);
}
/*
 *  ignore_line:
 *      Gets the next line (up to and including the newline
 *      character) from the file pointed to by fptr and
 *      promptly loses it.  Taken from asc2ah.c.
 *
 *          Siggi   29.06.1990
 */
int
ignore_line(dat_fp)
   FILE           *dat_fp;
{
   char            string[256];
   char           *fgets();
   if (fgets(string, 250, dat_fp) == NULL)  /* nothing there     */
      return (-1);
   return (0);          /* there was something   */
```

WHen I try to compile with gcc

```
gcc gi_line.c  vel2d.c -lm -o vel2d
vel2d.c: In function ‘main’:
vel2d.c:205:19: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
                   fprintf(stdout,"%.1f",index);
                   ^
vel2d.c:206:9: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
         else
         ^
```

I have included only fprintf line.Without that line I c can compile code and it works perfectly.So what should I change?

Comment: Where is the `fprintf` in your code snippet? (It's on line 205 and the offending `else` is on line 206. Your code doesn't have that many lines.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a compiling error that says error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587875/why-do-i-get-a-compiling-error-that-says-error-else-without-a-previous-if)

Comment: @MOehm - It's in the pastebin link. But the problem is just two statements after an `if` with an `else` after it. Nothing a pair of curly brackets wouldn't fix.

Comment: Oh god, it's 1969 again, and everything is horrible.

Comment: @MOehm I have changed pastebin,take a look!

Comment: @owacoder: Okay, I see it now. Typical case of "I don't need braces, it's just one statement" and "I'll just add a quick print statement for debuging here".

Comment: `return` is a statement, not a function. There is no need parenthetising the result and it should not be done in modern code with such a simple expression. Also the use of non-prototype function declarators is deprecated since a long time. The code is ancient and can include other outdated features which differ from standard C.

Comment: Don't post external links to code only. See [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the offending code in question:

```
       if (xflg)
              index = m * nxy + l*nx + k;
              fprintf(stdout,"%.1f",index);
       else
          index = m * nxy + k*ny + l;
```

The "if" and "else" sections of this `if` statement originally had one line each, so adding braces wasn't strictly necessary.  But when you added the call to `fprintf`, that changed things.

Since the are no braces after `if`, the `index = m * nxy + l*nx + k;` line consists of the entire `if` part.  The `printf` that follows is *not* part of the `if` and is a separate statement.  Then when the compiler sees the `else`, there's no corresponding `if` because the prior `if` is complete.

This can be fixed by adding the braces:

```
       if (xflg) {
              index = m * nxy + l*nx + k;
              fprintf(stdout,"%.1f",index);
       } else {
          index = m * nxy + k*ny + l;
       }
```

You should always add braces to any `if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, or `do` block, even if the body is only one line.  That prevents errors like this from happening.

You were lucky in this case that failing to add braces resulted in a compiler error.  If you didn't have an `else` part in this example, the code would compile and the `printf` would always run.  Then you'd be scratching your head to figure out why.

As for the `printf` warning, `index` is of type `int`, so you need to use the proper format specifier to print it which is `%d`.

Comment: How to write m,l,k in one line?I have tried fprintf(f,"%2d %d %2d\n",m,l,k); but it writes each in new line.