# I don’t understand the results that are getting printed

Tags: c

This program prints `6`.

If I uncomment the `//printf("yes");` line then it prints `8`, but not `yes`.

And if I remove the first `i++;` and leave the line blank, it prints `7`.

If I remove the second `i++;` it prints `5`.

What is the error?

```
int main () {

    int i = 3;

    if (!i)
        i++;
    i++;

    if (i == 3)
        //printf("yes");
        i += 2;
    i += 2;

    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: misleading indentation!

Comment: thats how its been given to me.and thats the point of my question and why does it work like that.

Comment: scope...check the scope...

Comment: Can't seem to find what? Just load this code in your debugger and watch the variable. Best way to learn.

Comment: If it was given to you in that poor shape, maybe it was intented as a lesson to learn that indentation does not define scopes. It's no replacement for `{  }`.

Comment: that was the purpose

Comment: Perhaps the original (misleading) indentation should be kept? As it is the gist of the problem. Both the double `i++;` and the double `i+=2;` were indented (relative to the 'if' statement) - possibly the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't have a curly brackets after the 'if' statements, only the line directly after them is conditional.  The indentation does nothing!

Option 1 Answer = 6:

```
int main ( ) 
{
    int i = 3;  //i==3
    if (!i) i++; // !3 = False Never Executed

    i++; // i==4

    if (i==3) i+=2; // i!=3, Never Executed

    i+=2; // i==6
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Option 1 Answer = 8:

```
int main ( ) 
{
    int i = 3;  //i==3
    if (!i) i++; // !3 = False Never Executed

    i++; // i==4

    if (i==3) printf("yes"); // i!=3 Never Executed

    i+=2; // i==6
    i+=2; // i==8
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but why isnt the yes beeing printed?

Comment: Because I never = 3 at that point in the code,  Let me add the other option.

Comment: I've fixed your indendation and moved everything onto one line that is executed as a single statement. hopefully this helps.

Comment: It helps.Thank you.It was too confusing to me.

Answer (score 6):

this program prints 6 and it's hard to get because of misleading indentation.

It's currently equivalent to:

```
int main ( ) {
int i = 3;
if (!i)
    {
       i++;
    }
    i++;  // this is executed whatever the previous if

if (i==3)
//printf("yes");
    {
       i+=2;   // could be executed because printf was commented, but isn't because of the value of i
    }

    i+=2;   // executed whatever the previous if
printf("%d", i);
return 0;
}
```

The second condition: if you leave the `printf` commented out, you'll execute the last `i+=2;`, else you'll execute both `i += 2` statements.

So 2 additions are performed: one adds 1 and one adds 2.

```
3 + 1 + 2 = 6
```

note that `gcc -Wall` does wonders on those cases (more precisely `-Wmisleading-indentation`). On your code:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:6:1: warning: this 'if' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentatio
n]
 if (!i)
 ^~
test.c:8:5: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as
if it is guarded by the 'if'
     i++;
     ^
test.c:10:1: warning: this 'if' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentati
on]
 if (i==3)
 ^~
test.c:13:5: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as
 if it is guarded by the 'if'
     i+=2;
     ^
```

as a conclusion: always protect your conditions with curly braces, even if there's only one instruction. This protects you against:

- code that is added afterwards, possibly by someone else, with the intent to add it in the condition but fails.
- macros which define 2 or more instructions and that don't follow the `do {} while(0)` pattern: only the first instruction in the macro is conditionned by the `if`

Answer (score 3):

I believe your confusion is because C allows you to leave the braces off an `if` statement, but only the immediately following statement counts as inside the `if` block.

```
if (!i)
    i++;
    i++;
```

That is the same as this.

```
if (!i) {
    i++;
}
i++;
```

This can be very confusing if you come from Ruby or Python where indentation is syntax.

While leaving the braces off can be convenient, it's also a great way to introduce bugs. Never use this feature.