# Why must this 'if' block with a single statement require a bracket to work properly?

Tags: c, if-statement

//Here is the sample code to print it's input one word per line:
//without bracket it doesn't work properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

main() {
  int c, state;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
      if (state == IN) {
        putchar('\n');
        state = OUT;
      } else {
        putchar(c);
        state = IN;
      }
  }
}
```

//when you put brackets around the nested if block(logically a single statement) inside the first if block it works properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

main() {
  int c, state;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
      if (state == IN) {
        putchar('\n');
        state = OUT;
      }
    } else {
      putchar(c);
      state = IN;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You really should indent your code to make it more readable (Run it through `clang-format` or GNU `indent` if you're not using an IDE with a reformatting feature)... which might show you the issue too.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will not forget to indent my code from the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you indent the code you can see the difference.

Version with no braces:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

main()
{
    int c, state;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
            if(state == IN)
            {
                putchar('\n');
                state = OUT;
            }
            else
            {
                putchar(c);
                state = IN;
            }
    }
}
```

Version with braces:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

main()
{
    int c, state;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        {
            if(state == IN)
            {
                putchar('\n');
                state = OUT;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(c);
            state = IN;
        }
    }
}
```

In the first version, the `else` block is associated with the nested `if`, so it only prints the character when `c` is one of the delimiter characters and `state != IN`.

In the second version the `else` block goes with the test against the delimiter characters, so all non-delimiter characters are printed.

An `else` statement is always associated with the most recent `if` in the same block. The braces in the second version put the nested `if` in a block of its own, so `else` will not be associated with it, so it goes with the outer `if`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version you outer `if` body is this

```
      if (state == IN) {
        putchar('\n');
        state = OUT;
      } else {
        putchar(c);
        state = IN;
      }
```

While in the second is this

```
      if (state == IN) {
        putchar('\n');
        state = OUT;
      }
```

So with the second one the `else` is associated with the outer `if`, with the first it is with the inner `if`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the `else` statement is binding the the second `if` statement.

```
if () if () {} else () {}
```

Which is equivalent to...

```
if () { if () {} else () {} }
```

In the second example, the `else` statement is binding to the first `if` statement.

```
if () { if () {} } else () {}
```

This occurs because the added brackets enclose the second `if` statement inside a block scope, where the `else` exists outside of that scope. Without the added brackets, the `else` lies within the same scope as the second `if` and is interpreted as a single chained statement.