# Compilation error in C just because of indentation?

Tags: c

I created a simple C program that creates a square according to the users input 4 = 4x4, 5 = 5x5 etc.

My program was not compiling correctly like it is below, and after a while I was able to fix it by removing indentation from the second printf.

Is this normal? or is this just my IDE? I'm very new to C but in general I've never seen indentation affect code functionality, so I just wanted to understand a bit more about that.

Thanks!

```
int main(void)
{
 
 int height;
 
 do 
 {
     
    height = get_int("Height: ");
 
 }
    while (height>9 || height<1);
    
 
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 

{
   for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
   
     printf ("#");
     printf ("\n");

   
   }

}
```

Error:

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    mario.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o mario
mario.c:24:6: error: misleading indentation; statement is not part of the previous 'for' [-Werror,-Wmisleading-indentation]
     printf ("\n");
     ^
mario.c:21:4: note: previous statement is here
   for (int j = 0; j : mario] Error 1
```

Comment: *indentation*? In C there are blocks with curly braces so *indentation* has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What was the compilation error?

Comment: Can you paste the error message which you get? @Starchest

Comment: Aside: Using `printf()` for a single character is massive overkill; use `putchar()` etc. instead.

Comment: C is not sensitive to whitespace like indentation.  My IDE complains about the indentation of your `printf ("\n");` being misleading because it is not part of the `for`

Comment: Maybe you unnoticedly removed a spurious '{' /' }' - for-j has no opening `{`. Indentation is almost irrelevant

Comment: @possum Correct. Same here, so I guess that the "for" can only have 1 line of instruction be a part of it? What if I did want to print both of those things as part of the "for"? It's not what I want to do, but not sure if it should not let me do it at all.
Thank you!

Comment: A good programmer always uses braces. Stops the embarrassment of getting caught with your trousers down.

Comment: I guess the compiler is turning warnings into errors

Comment: @Starchest `for` can have many lines.  You need to explicitly put them between `{` and `}` so it is not ambiguous

Comment: Hey @EdHeal thank you. 

So, I was able to get away without using braces, but if I had written it correctly, the printf's would be in different braces each, correct?

Comment: Yes - Always uses braces. Prevents a lot of problems

Comment: You do not show us the code which actually fails to compile. You show us a similar one, but not the same DV-ting.

Comment: This is only a warning but you treat warnings as errors

Comment: @EdHeal The funny part of this question is that OP did not show us the code which triggers this warning :D

Comment: He did give the correct code, but the edit by @asuka totally broke the question...

Answer (score 8):

Warning about misleading indentation is not a part of standard C. It is an [extension provided by Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wmisleading-indentation) and is enabled by the [`-Wall`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wall) switch you used (directly or through a setting in your IDE). Using `-Werror` elevates the warning to an error.

This is a recent addition to Clang (it is in Clang 12 but not in Apple’s Clang 11), and using `-Wall` is aggressive, so it may include new warning features in the future.

Comment: But what is misleading about it? Looks properly indented to me.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: The post says “My program was not compiling correctly like it is below”. Meaning OP pasted the passing code, not the code that generated the message. Sigh. Humans. “Here is a thing that works. Why does the other thing that I am not showing not work?”

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP did not show us the code which triggers this warning.

Comment: @0___________: That is what I wrote.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yep I did not read the comment only answer

Comment: The diagnostic can also come if the indentation looks correct on screen, but one line uses tabs and the other uses spaces

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I reformatted the original post, see edit history for the original code (it was not formatted).

Answer (score 7):

Indentation does not affect the compile result. The "error" `clang` gives out should be instead a **warning**, but it becomes an error since `clang` is asked to do it because it is called with some `-W` options (probably instructed by the IDE):

```
-Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow
```

and between these ones, `-Werror` make all warnings into errors:

```
       -Werror
           Make all warnings into errors.
```

And other `-Wall` `-Wextra` etc. tells the compiler to treat some certain things that are not treated as warnings as warnings.

If `-Werror` is removed from the option for the compiler commandline options in the IDE, the code can be compiled successfully.

Take a closer look at the error message:

```
mario.c:24:6: error: misleading indentation; statement is not part of the previous 'for' [-Werror,-Wmisleading-indentation]
     printf ("\n");
     ^
```

Those ones in the brackets `[-Werror,-Wmisleading-indentation]` indicates why this comes up. If `-Werror` is removed, this error will restores to be a warning, and if `-Wmisleading-indentation` (and maybe `-Wall`? I am not familiar with warning options) is removed, you won't see any complains about this line, no matter whether `-Werror` is on.

Answer (score 3):

Add curly braces, the compiler is not sure if you mean

```
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
{
   printf ("#");
}
printf ("\n");

or

for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
{
   printf ("#");
   printf ("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***You did not show us the code which triggers this warning***. This warning is emitted to warn the programmer that he probably forgot the braces. It is especially handy for the programmers who save their keyboards and have a "braces" allergy. I personally always put braces. It does not hurt but often it saves hours of debugging.

This code will emit the warning:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            printf ("#");
            printf ("\n");
    }
```

This one will not:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            printf ("#");
        printf ("\n");
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YqqKW8

[image]

Comment: I reformatted the original post, see edit history for the original code (it was not formatted).