# Misleading indentation; statement is not part of the previous 'if' [-Werror,-Wmisleading-indentation]

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

Here I'm trying to write the C code, but I've stuck in the error,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int width = 0;
    while (! (width >= 1) || ! (width <= 8))
    {
        printf("Enter the width of the Pyramid: ");
        scanf("%i", &width);
    }

    printf("%i\n", width);

    for (int i=0; i<=width; i++)
    {
        int k = width - (i+1);

        for (int j=0; j<=width; j++)
        {
            if (j == k)
                printf("#");
                k++;

            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

#### Error message

```
**misleading indentation; statement is not part of the previous 'if' [-Werror,-Wmisleading-indentation]
                printf("#");
                ^
mario.c:21:13: note: previous statement is here
            if (j==k)
            ^
mario.c:25:13: error: expected expression
            else
            ^
2 errors generated.**
```

[image: Here is visuals of image]

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't expect a compiler to warn about it.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I'm if there is anything wrong in my post

Comment: What compiler? The title suggests it is GCC — GCC has such detection, e.g., explicitly by [-Wmisleading-indentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmisleading-indentation) (the TAB size can be set by [-ftabstop](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-ftabstop) - the default is, unfortunately, 8).

Comment: Why is this tagged with [CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this piece of code:

```
            if (j==k)
                printf("#");
                k++;
                
            else
                printf(" ");
```

The indentation suggests that the line `k++;` is part of the body of the `if` statement, but it is not.  Because there are no braces after the `if`, the body consists only of the following line, i.e. `printf("#");`.  That also means that the `else` that follows has no corresponding `if` and is a syntax error.

You should always put braces around `if` blocks as well as `for` and `while` loops:

```
            if (j==k) {
                printf("#");
                k++;
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
```